# 2000s dystopian future where a woman ends up with things in her mind that communicate with her

Tags: story-identification, books

The cover had an illustrated picture of a woman with long flowing red hair.

It was based in the future. I really want to say she was a detective or police officer.  She ended up going through some kind of procedure to have things implanted that communicate with her and light up in her mind. I am also fairly certain they try to convince her to take a drug that is destroying the world.

I can only for sure say I am talking about a book where a woman ends up with things in her mind that communicate to her and light up.

Comment: Maybe *The Host*?

https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/81luvu3AzfL._SY445_.jpg

Comment: Thank you for your response but it was definitely before 2008 and I really don’t think written by Meyer. I would have recognized her from the Twilight series. And I don’t think this was ever adapted into a film as nobody seems to have any idea what I am talking about. Also I am 99% certain there were no aliens involved. Probably going to at least watch The Host now to make sure though.

Answer (score 6):

Is it possible this is a slight mis-recollection of [*Star Hunters*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?32012) (or one of the other [*Diadem*](https://www.goodreads.com/series/40567-diadem) novels) by Jo Clayton?

[image: Cover of Star Hunters portraying Aleytys]

This cover in particular shows Aleytys, who is described as having long straight red hair.

*Star Hunters* mostly matches the points you recall, except it's from the 1980s, not the 2000s.

- In *Star Hunters*, Aleytys has joined (as of *Maeve*, the previous book, actually) Hunters Inc., a for-profit organization based on the world Wolff that sells services tracking and finding people and objects.  (Like detectives who also have to retrieve who/what they're searching for.)
- At the start of the book Aleytys and Head are discussing her surgery for the biologic implants that Hunters Inc. augments their operatives with.
- Aleytys has the titular *Diadem*, a magic-technology artifact that has embedded itself in her head:

  - Use of the diadem is typically described as a manifestation of lights;
  - The diadem contains the captured/stored personalities of previous owners/users who can talk to Aleytys and help her.
- At one point Aleytys is temporarily implanted with a control device by an enemy.

I don't recall anything about drugs, though.  But it does definitely match the minimum facts you recall.

Answer (score 3):

[image: Cover1]

This sounds a good bit like [Brain Plague](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/121609.Brain_Plague), part of the Elysian Cycle by Joan Slonczewski.  Published in 2000.  The main character, Chrys, is a starving artist in the far future on another planet.  Desperate for funds and health care, she signs up for a kind of surgery to host a colony of microbes or "brain enhancers" who happen to feed off of arsenic, azetidine, or "ace" in the bloodstream. **Medical procedure like an implant.**

Chrys learns that her new occupants are chatty,  friendly, and worship her as a god.  Because of their short lifespans, she has to attend to them, or even the kindest colonies will try to overthrow their host and take what they can get from the bloodstream. They appear in colors that not every race can see, twinkling and shining.  They can manipulate dopamine and at one point try to convince her to let them dominate her body in exchange for a high (I think it was called "endless light"). **Lights and colors.**

Because of social and political issues, an elven race tries to manipulate carriers/hosts by training the microbes to attack the host and slowly kill them, but not before infecting others.  The infected "vampires" are drug addicts for arsenic for the microbial colonies.  **Drugs.**

The community of carriers are more than just hosts, to speak to your point about detectives.  Chrys ends up learning about other hosts through various chats with microbe transfers and begins to help a friend who is much more deeply involved in the politics.  There is a network of humans and other races trying to keep the use of the brain enhancers safe, and between the police, user agents, and medics, they suspect a sinister plot.  **Detective work.**

This image of the cover shows the main character with red hair.  Color and the brilliance of light was a big theme as different races could see different parts of the spectrum; she even named her "people" after colors.  The microbes can also "flash" at other hosts through the carrier's eyes. They communicate with hosts quite conversationally and twinkle as lights in her viewport.  **Communication and light.**

Related: [Novel with a female protagonist who can see ultraviolets](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/211073/novel-with-a-female-protagonist-who-can-see-ultraviolets-other-world-symbiotic/211084#211084)